# how to balance the time between doing cousulting project for PHD advisor and doing my own company

Tags: startup

i have enrolled in Fudan university this fall. but there is a good opportunite for me to cooperate with my friend to start up my own company.  i am puzzled how to balance the energy and time between this two ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I do not believe it relates to Project Management as you have currently expressed it. Please consider whether it could be made more directly related to the main topic of this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Project Management. You may find it is on-topic on the Workplace SE site here: http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  Drop one.  You have two endeavors that should only compete with your home life and rest.  One of those, going to school, could be part-time, allowing for part-time work, but starting up a company is not part-time.  It requires 100% commitment, competing only with home and rest time.